# RxSwift Sequence of observables from array

Tags: swift, rx-swift

On my application I have to download several files from Amazon S3, for that purpose I have created a function that download a single files and return and observable. I have also created a second function that I have called downloadAll. The purpose of this function is to download each S3 files sequentially.

As some of the files are big and there are a lot of files (more than 50) If I just merge all the observables I end up with a lot of timeouts from amazon because of concurrency.

What I have tried:

**Merge with concurrency**

```
    let observables = self.syncItem!.files.map { (f) in
        return Observable.of(f)
    }
    let o = Observable.from(observables).merge(maxConcurrent: 2)
```

**Result:** I get the two first files downloaded but the others are not been downloaded.

**ConcatMap**

```
    return Observable.from(self.syncItem?.files).concatMap({ (file) in
        return self.downloadS3File(file: file)
    })
```

**Result:** Only the first file been downloaded

**DownloadS3FileFunction is ommitted ... it is working ok for a single file download and its emit a File object upon download completion **

I have searched a LOT before asking the question. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the first file is downloaded when you use `concatMap` then the problem is in your `downloadS3File(file:)` function. It doesn't emit a completed event when it's finished downloading the file so the concatMap doesn't start the second download.

That's likely the problem with your other solution as well.

Comment: Actually I am only emitting a next event not complete... I will emit a complete event and return. Thanks for your feedback ! :D

Comment: yep that was the problem just setting observable.onComplete() after onNext fix the issue... thanks again